# Handling propagating errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code I have a main function, which calls a function that reads some data from a file and returns this data, which is then used in diffrent ways. Obviously there is a risk that the user inputs a filename that is not to be found, resulting in an error. I want to catch this error and output a error message written by me without the traceback etc. I tried using a standard try-except statement, which works almost as intended, except now the data is not read so there are new errors as I try to calculate using empty variabels. Using `sys.exit` or `raise SystemExit` in the exception block results in errors beeig written in the console with tracebacks and the whole point of catching the first error feels redundant. I could wrap the whole program in a try-statement, but I have never seen that being done and it feels wrong. How can I either terminate the program in a clean way or hide all the subsequent errors?

```
    def getData(fileName):
        try:
            file = open(fileName,"r")
            data = file.readlines()
            file.close()
            x = []
            y = []
            for i in data:
                noNewline = i.rstrip('\n')
                x.append(float(noNewline.split("\t")[0]))
                y.append(float(noNewline.split("\t")[1]))
            return x,y
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Some error messages")

    def main(fileName):
        x,y = getData(fileName)
        # diffrent calculations with x and y
```

Comment: make the try and except in main

Comment: Do you mean around the whole inside of the main or just around the one line I wrote in the example? The second alternativ doesn't work and the first seems kind of imprecise and clumsy as the main function is rather big. But maybe I'm just way to new to have a gut feeling on code aesthteics...

Comment: You need to make try when there is a code that is problematic. For example, make try and catch when calling `getData`, that raise an error, and if there is a catch print error and stop the program or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `main` is a function, you could `return` on an error:

```
def main(filename):
    try:
        x, y = getData(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("file not found")
        return

    # calculations here
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

`sys.exit` and `SystemExit` take optional arguments—0 is considered a successful termination.

### Example

```
sys.exit(0)
raise SystemExit(0)
```

## References

Python sys.exit: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit

Comment: This seems to work if the main function is called when you run the program, but if you run the program without actually calling function, but rather call the function in the next line in the console, this returns both FileNotFoundError and SystemExit error. Why is that?

Comment: @BenjaS I'm not sure what you're asking. This works for me when calling from `main` and when calling `getData` directly from Python 3.8.5 REPL.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but I tried again and this time using REPL and there was no problem so I guess it's a problem with my spyder settings... anyhow thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

below

```
def getData(fileName):
    file = open(fileName,"r")
    data = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in data:
        noNewline = i.rstrip('\n')
        x.append(float(noNewline.split("\t")[0]))
        y.append(float(noNewline.split("\t")[1]))
    return x,y


def main(fileName):
    # if you only want to handle exception coming from 'getData'
    try:
        x,y = getData(fileName)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'could not get data using file {filename}. Reason: {str(e)}')
        return
    # do something with x,y
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('get_the_file_name_from_somewhere.txt')
```